# Python Aiogram, how to get correct file url?

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, aiogram

I use this code,

```
    file_id = product.image
    file = await bot.get_file(file_id=file_id)
    url = bot.get_file_url(file_path=file)
```

but it returns incorrect url

<https://api.telegram.org/file/bot5111628696:AAEecgE_1eVHUqaV7fhU8uvYXZVq1m-HUzs/{"file_id": "AgACAgIAAxkDAAIOvGMZ_JFrhgbY1szdAZ3Zgp-26RhEAAKiwDEbdfJwSGTCUaTjIBk9AQADAgADcwADKQQ", "file_unique_id": "AQADosAxG3XycEh4", "file_size": 1124, "file_path": "photos/file_3.jpg"}>

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the url of the file is "photos/file_3.jpg", to get it:

```py
    file_id = product.image
    file = await bot.get_file(file_id=file_id)
    obj_url = bot.get_file_url(file_path=file)
    url = **obj_url["file_path"]
```

The get_file method returns us a [file](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#file) object, and it has 4 fields

Comment: this is supposed to be like recursion, when you refer to an object it returns the object itself

Comment: if you don't believe it, try comparing file with obj_url, file == obj_url ? A True result is returned